# how to change "command palette border" color in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to change "command palette border" color in vscode. command palette show up when you type `Command+Shift+P or Ctrl+Shift+P(⇧⌘P)`

[image: command palette image]

I read [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color) docs but I can't find solution. I am struggling to change the border color to make palette be more conspicuous.

anyone knows the solution?

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I can find to do this is by modifying the contrastBorder setting.

Add this to your settings.json (Command+Shift+P or Ctrl+Shift+P(⇧⌘P) then choose "Preferences: Open Settings UI") file:

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Theme Name",
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "[Theme Name]": {
            "contrastBorder": "#ff0000"
        }
    }
}
```

Beware, this also changes the border color of a lot of other layout elements.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Taylor's answer, it is the `quickInput`'s border specifically you would want to change.  But there doesn't appear to be a setting to allow that.

You could change the command palette's background to help your problem using:

```
"quickInput.background": "#333",  // command palette(s) bg
"quickInput.foreground": "#fff",
```

`contrastBorder` does work but changes the border color of a couple of other elements as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's

`"widget.border"`

I found it by inspecting vscode built in dev tools

[Dev tools with widget.border style visible in the inspect element pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JMJE.png)